Open AI Assistant file parsing
Currently I am working on the following task. I need to receive the CV as a file from the backend. File could be pdf/docx and could include the image. I need to parse this file and return its content as a JSON.
I have built the followinf service on my NodeJS service.
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import { environment } from '../common/data/environment';
import { checkmimeType, OpenAiFileUploadReponse } from '../common';
import axios from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export class GPTService {
    private readonly openai: OpenAI;
    private readonly BASE_PATH: string;
    private assistant_id: string;

    constructor() {
        this.openai = new OpenAI({
            apiKey: environment.gpt_key,
        });
        this.BASE_PATH = 'https://api.openai.com/v1';
        this.assistant_id = environment.assistant_id as string;
    }

    async createRun(thread_id: string, assistant_id: string) {
        return this.openai.beta.threads.runs.create(thread_id, {
            assistant_id
        });
    }

    async waitForTheResponse(run: OpenAI.Beta.Threads.Runs.Run) {
        let { status } = run;

        while (status === 'queued' || status === 'in_progress') {
            const retrieving_run = await this.openai.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(run.thread_id, run.id);

            if (retrieving_run.status === 'completed') {
                const all_messages = await this.openai.beta.threads.messages.list(run.thread_id);
                this.openai.beta.threads.del(run.thread_id);
                all_messages.data.map((d) => console.log(d.content[0]))
                // console.dir(all_messages);
                // console.dir(all_messages.data[0].content[0]);
                return all_messages.data[0].content[0];
            } else if (retrieving_run.status === 'queued' || retrieving_run.status === 'in_progress') {
                status = retrieving_run.status;
                continue;
            } else {
                console.log("Status >>> ", retrieving_run.status);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    async createThread(file_id: string) {
        return this.openai.beta.threads.create({
            messages: [
                {
                    role: 'user',
                    content: `Return me the content of the file in the JSON format`,
                    attachments: [{
                        file_id,
                        tools: [{
                            type: 'file_search'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    async extractFileContent(file?: Express.Multer.File) {
        const { id } = await this.uploadFile(file);
        const { id: thread_id } = await this.createThread(id);
        const run = await this.createRun(thread_id, this.assistant_id);
        const content = await this.waitForTheResponse(run);
        await this.deleteFile(id);
        return content;
    }

    async deleteFile(id: string) {
        const res = await this.openai.files.del(id);

        console.log(res);

        return res;
    }

    async uploadFile(file?: Express.Multer.File) {
        if (!file) {
            throw new Error('File is corrupted or is not downloaded!');
        }

        const isValidType = checkmimeType(file.mimetype);

        if (!isValidType) {
            throw new Error('Mime type is not valid!');
        }

        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file.buffer, {
            filename: file.originalname,
            contentType: file.mimetype
        });
        form.append('purpose', 'assistants');

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`${this.BASE_PATH}/files`, form, {
                headers: {
                    ...form.getHeaders(),
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${environment.gpt_key}`,
                },
            });

            console.log('Upload response:', response.data);

            if (response.data && response.data.id) {
                return response.data as OpenAiFileUploadReponse;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to upload file to OpenAI.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
            throw new Error('Error uploading file: ' + error);
        }
    }
}

I am calling the method extractFileContent to run the main process. It includes a few steps:

I am uploading a file to the openAI storage using the method uploadFile
Creating a new thread using the createThread method
Create the run using the previously created assistant id (stores in my env) and calling the method createRun. Note: assistant uses gpt-4o model
And in the ``waitForResponse``` method I am getting the result of my GPT Assistant work
It should work but... I am getting the strange response, like "I don/t have the access to this file". Or this file wasn't uploaded. But the main problem, that it is.

I have attached the uploaded file id here:
messages: [
                {
                    role: 'user',
                    content: `Return me the content of the file in the JSON format`,
                    attachments: [{
                        file_id,
                        tools: [{
                            type: 'file_search'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]

Maybe I have missed something? I will be very appreciated for your answer or any assistance
